# R plot x and y are different lengths

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a data frame I created from a csv where it goes DataTime, value1, value2, and the datetime is represented like this MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM.

Whenever I try to run the command plot(dataFrame[1], dataFrame[2]), I get the error 'x' and 'y' lengths differ.  I've checked both of the columns, and they have the same number of items.

Is there something else I'm missing, or am I comparing two different things and it's causing the plot function to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: 
   `plot(dataFrame[,1], dataFrame[,2])`
this way you pull the entire column